# MongooseDB Error: Operation `levels.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms

Tags: node.js, mongoose, discord, discord.js, bots

I am trying to make a leveling system for my bot (discord.js) and I am using mongoose for the database. Whenever I run the command the bot crashes and this is the error I get:

```
C:\Users\Liam\Desktop\slashcmds\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:158
          const err = new MongooseError(message);
                      ^

MongooseError: Operation `levels.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Liam\Desktop\slashcmds\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:158:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:564:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:507:7)
```

Here is my code:

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const { EmbedBuilded, AttachmentBuilder, Embed, EmbedBuilder } = require(`discord.js`);
const { Canvacord } = require('canvacord');
const levelSchema = require(`../../Schemas.js/level`);

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('rank')
    .setDescription("Get a server member's XP rank")
    .addUserOption(option => option.setName('target').setDescription("This is the user you want to check the XP rank of.").setRequired(false)),
    async execute(interaction) {
        const { options, user, guild } = interaction;
        const Member = options.getUser('target');
        const member = guild.members.cache.get(Member.id);
        const Data = await levelSchema.findOne({ Guild: guild.id, User: member.id });

        const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setColor('Blue')
        .setTitle(`${member.user.username}'s XP Rank`)
        .setDescription(`${member.user.username} has not gained any XP yet.`)

        if(!Data) return await interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed] });
        await interaction.deferRepy();

        const Required = Data.Level * Data.Level * 20 + 20;
        const rank = new Canvacord.rank()
        .setAvatar(member.displayAvatarURL({ forseStatic: true}))
        .setBackground("IMAGE", `https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1055548593186025513/1057353099720798308/OIP.jpg`)
        .setCurrentXP(Data.XP)
        .setRequiredXP(Required)
        .setRank(1, "Rank", false)
        .setLevel(Data.Level, "Level")
        .setUsername(member.user.username)
        .setDiscriminator(member.user.discriminator)

        const Card = await rank.build();
        const attachment = new AttachmentBuilder(Card, { name: "rank.png" });

        const embed2 = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setColor("Blue")
        .setTitle(`${member.user.username}'s XP Rank`)
        .setImage("attachment://rank.png")

        await interaction.editReply({ embeds: [embed2], files: [attachment] });
    }
}
```

The bot would crash and send the message "Application did not respond".

Anyone knows how to fix this? I've looked online and nothing shows up for this error.

Comment: Are you properly connected to db?

Comment: No, I forgot about that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the model before the connection is established.

According to [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#buffering)

> Mongoose lets you start using your models immediately, without waiting for mongoose to establish a connection to MongoDB.

Use `mongoose.connect(uri)` with async await to establish connection with database and run the command again.